# What is the 'wildcard address' In the context of UDP Broadcasts?

Tags: java, network-programming, broadcast, multicast, datagram

Referring to the [Java 6 API docs for the DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) class:

> UDP broadcasts sends are always enabled on a DatagramSocket. In order
>   to receive broadcast packets a **DatagramSocket should be bound to the
>   wildcard address**. In some implementations, broadcast packets may also
>   be received when a DatagramSocket is bound to a more specific address.

Could someone tell me what the 'wildcard address' is? And is the following valid for listening for UDP broadcasts:

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"),4445);
```

Comment: Here http://www.rhyshaden.com/ipadd.htm is a whole section on Wildcards :) For listening to broadcasts a wildcard-bound DatagramSocket should be enough.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472269/java-datagramsocket-listening-on-a-broadcast-address

Comment: Carlo, that is indeed what I based my above example upon but I wondered if using 0.0.0.0 is 'good practice'..

Comment: Well, it's the only practice doing the job of listening to broadcasts from any sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard address is `0.0.0.0.` Not to be confused with the broadcast-to-all-subnets address, which is `255.255.255.255.` It is more correctly called the 'any' address, after `INADDR_ANY.`

In Java it is most easily used by supplying `null` as a bind-address, or omitting the parameter altogether, e.g. `new InetSocketAddress(null, 0)` or `new InetSocketAddress(0)` respectively. In other words it is the default when binding, and therefore implicitly 'good practice'.